# CSS Transition Left/Right Not Working

Tags: css

I'll preface this with the fact that I'm no CSS expert, but I can't figure out why this isn't working. I want my DIV that contains the images to slide left and right when i hover over the left and right parts of the container. The sliding works fine, but the transition does not...

HTML:

```
<div class="event-pics-container">
     <div class="slide slide-left"></div>
     <div class="slide slide-right"></div>
     <div class="event-pics-area" ng-show="eventImages.length">
         <div ng-repeat="pic in eventImages">
             <img src="{{pic.EncodedAbsUrl}}" alt="{{pic.Title}}" title="{{pic.Title}}" ng-click="siteProps.EventLogo = pic.EncodedAbsUrl">
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.event-pics-container{
   position:relative;height:100px;width:100%;background-color:black;overflow:hidden;
}
.event-pics-container .slide{
   position:absolute;top:0px;z-index:1000;height:100%;width:30px;background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
.event-pics-container .slide-left{
   left:0px;
}
.event-pics-container .slide-right{
   right:0px;
}
.event-pics-container .slide-left:hover + .event-pics-area{
   -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
   left:0px;
}
.event-pics-container .slide-right:hover + .event-pics-area{
   -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
   right:0px;
}
.event-pics-area{
   position:absolute;height:100px;white-space:nowrap;
}
.event-pics-area > div{
height:100px;width:100px;display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;position:relative;
}
.event-pics-area img{
   height:100%;cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear but what you don't seem to have set both the **start and end** values to which the transition should go. Perhaps a demo would clarify matters.

Comment: I added Opacity: 0.1 to the transition (along with Left and Right) and the Opacity seems to work fine...

Comment: This is what you have now with the code you provided: http://jsbin.com/macicejeja/2/edit  --- If that is the case, the code your provided doesn't keep 'state'. Would you like it to keep state? Utilizing JS or just go back to the original state? IE: left:0px

Comment: Havent gotten that far, but yes, id like to keep state...